# Add Volume Control to Itunes Jump List

Tags: windows-7, itunes, taskbar, jumplist

Is it possible to add a volume control to iTunes' Jump List? The pause and skip buttons are useful, but a volume slider would make it so much better. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd say it's impossible, but per app volume control from the jump list would be interesting!

Comment: After all, Windows already has this feature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far on the program itself can create it's jumplist. There is no way (AFAIK) to inject code into another processes jumplist.

So, no.